# Collections Counter over a list of Tuples

Tags: python, counter

I'm trying to get the Python Counter work over a list of tuples.

```
ListOfTuples = [('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly'),('East', 'West', 'South'), ('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly'), ('NewYork', 'Berlin', 'Austria'),('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly')]
```

What I am looking for is a simple counter which throws out :

```
('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly') = 3
('East', 'West', 'South') = 1
('NewYork', 'Berlin', 'Austria') = 1
```

When I looked up on SO, I found the one below which works between tuples:

```
def count_ngrams(iterable, n=2):
    return Counter(zip(*[islice(iterable, i, None) for i in range(n)]))
count_ngrams(iterable, n=2)
```

When, I ran the above code on the example I get

```
Counter({(('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly'), ('East', 'West', 'South')): 1, (('East', 'West', 'South'), ('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly')): 1, (('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly'), ('NewYork', 'Berlin', 'Austria')): 1, (('NewYork', 'Berlin', 'Austria'), ('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly')): 1})
```

Comment: `print(Counter(ListOfTuples))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just call `Counter()` on the list of tuples:

```
Counter(ListOfTuples)
```

Which will give you:

```
Counter({('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly'): 3, ('East', 'West', 'South'): 1, ('NewYork', 'Berlin', 'Austria'): 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for iterative solution:

```
import collections
ListOfTuples = [('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly'),('East', 'West', 'South'), ('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly'), ('NewYork', 'Berlin', 'Austria'),('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly')]

Occurences = collections.defaultdict(int)

for item in ListOfTuples:
    Occurences[item] +=1
print(Occurences)
```

Outputs as:

```
>> defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly'): 3, ('East', 'West', 'South'): 1, ('NewYork', 'Berlin', 'Austria'): 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `dict(Counter(ListOfTuples))` which returns a dictionary rather than an Counter object.

O/P:

```
{('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly'): 3,
 ('East', 'West', 'South'): 1,
 ('NewYork', 'Berlin', 'Austria'): 1}
```

Comment: Well `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, so this is not really needed. `Counter` behaves like a normal dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below,

```
from collections import Counter
ListOfTuples = [('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly'),('East', 'West', 'South'), ('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly'), ('NewYork', 'Berlin', 'Austria'),('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly')]
dict(Counter(ListOfTuples))
```

Output

```
{('Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly'): 3,
 ('East', 'West', 'South'): 1,
 ('NewYork', 'Berlin', 'Austria'): 1}
```